# Adding two variables to empty array using push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, push

I need some help with this code. I get an unexpected token error.

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ; (8:11)`

> 1. Declare two variables, a string and an integer named fullName and birthYear, and set them equal to "Linus Torvalds" and 1969.

```
var fullName="Linus Torvalds";
var birthYear= 1969;
```

> 2. Declare an empty array called myArray.

```
var myArray=[];
```

> 3. Add the variables from #1 (fullName and birthYear) to myArray using the push method. Print myArray to the console.

```
myArray.push(fullName, birthYear);
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: What s your code ?

Comment: That code works just fine. What's your environment? Browser (which)? Node.js?

Comment: Provide the stack trace, please. 'Unexpected token error' can mean anything.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ; (8:11)

Comment: So, you're missing a semicolon ``;`` in line 8. But you haven't shown us the line 8. You should post your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myArray.push({
   fullName : fullName,
   birthYear : birthYear
});
```